# Clarification on ZVals

Tags: php

I was reading this: http://www.dereleased.com/2011/04/27/the-importance-of-zvals-and-circular-references/

And there's an example that lost me a bit.

```
$foo = &$bar;
$bar = &$foo;
$baz = 'baz';

$foo = &$baz;

var_dump($foo, $bar);
/*
string(3) "baz"
NULL
*/
```

> If you’ve been following along, this should make perfect sense. $foo
>   is created, and pointed at a ZVal location identified by $bar; when
>   $bar is created, it points at the same place $foo was pointed. That
>   location, of course, is null. When $foo is reassigned, the only thing
>   that changes is to which ZVal $foo points; if we had assigned a
>   different value to $foo first, then $bar would still retain that
>   value.

I learned to program in C. I understand that PHP is different and it uses ZVals instead of memory locations as references.  But when you run this code:

```
$foo = &$bar;
$bar = &$foo;
```

It seems to me that there would be two ZVals.  In C there would be two memory locations (and the values would be of the opposite memory location).

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It mostly comes down to how the *symbol table* works. It's a table with two sides:

```
symbol name  |  value
-------------+-------
             |
```

The fun thing is that a value can be assigned more than one name:

```
symbol name  |  value
-------------+-------
foo, bar     | 'baz'
```

When assigning to a symbol using `=`, the `value` side of the table is changed:

```
$baz = 42;

symbol name  |  value
-------------+-------
baz          | 42
```

When assigning using `=&`, the `symbol name` side is moved to wherever the value is:

```
$foo =& $baz;

symbol name  |  value
-------------+-------
baz, foo     | 42
```

So in your example, starting from scratch:

```
$foo =& $bar;
($bar does not exist, is null, which is implicitly created,
 $foo is pointed to where the implicitly created $bar points)

symbol name  |  value
-------------+-------
foo, bar     | null


$bar = &$foo;
(no real change, $bar is pointed to where $foo is pointing)

symbol name  |  value
-------------+-------
foo, bar     | null


$baz = 'baz';

symbol name  |  value
-------------+-------
foo, bar     | null
baz          | 'baz'


$foo = &$baz;
($foo is pointed to where $baz is pointing)

symbol name  |  value
-------------+-------
bar          | null
baz, foo     | 'baz'
```

Comment: So it's because it all works though the symbol table.  When I see $a =& $b I should think, "Move $a to be on the same row of the symbol table as $b" not, "Resolve $a as though it is $b".

Comment: Right. `=& x` is basically *"establish a reference to the same value as x"*, where "reference" is simply done with an entry in the symbol table.